# Java.io.FileOutputStream in Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Why "FileOutputStream" is a restricted class in Google App Engine? Is there any other way to use the "FileOutputStream" in Google App Engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java.io.FileOutputStream` is a restricted class in Google App Engine for Java because GAE/J apps are not allowed to write data to their local file systems. Therefore, GAE/J apps cannot use this class directly.

By connecting or communicating with applications outside of GAE, writing to a file system (and thus using `java.io.FileOutputStream` indirectly) may be possible.

GAE/J apps can store persistent data within the Google Cloud environment in ways other than by writing to a local file system.